# MySQL and MariaDB on same macOS via brew

Tags: mysql, mariadb, installation, homebrew

How do I install mariadb on my macOS Mojave via homebrew without destroying my MySQL 8 setup ?

> Error: Cannot install mariadb because conflicting formulae are
> installed.   mysql: because mariadb, mysql, and percona install the
> same binaries
>
> Please `brew unlink mysql` before continuing.

Comment: Put each in a Docker.

Comment: Use existing container images which work on macOS. Note use named volumes as recommended in Docker documentation.